# Obtain NetNTLM/NTLM hash or login

Tags: authentication, network, windows-10, ntlm

In one CTF, I encountered a task that is solved by getting NetNTLM \ NTLM or just getting username.

Tell me, please, is there any protocol that automatically sends NetNTLM / NTLM or username, when the connection is initialized?

The victim uses Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths:

`\\myserver\resource`

The types of attacks that use this is sending a word document with an image embedded in it using a UNC path as the reference

`\\192.168.0.1\image.jpg`

Your machine will try to authenticate to the share to get the image and in doing so pass along the NetNTLM hash.